# Paypal Payment Button - "Finish checkout" URL sometimes does not contain transaction details

Tags: paypal

We use "Paypal Payment Button " in our web-site.

From some reason the "Finish checkout URL" sometimes does not contain any transaction details, and arrives with no parameters, although we got the actual payment.

How can it be?